# How to use model mapper to map Generic Types with Collection Objects?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I am trying to map two generic types using http://modelmapper.org/ library representing DAO and Model classes -

**Model Classes -**

```
public class PageModel<T> {

    @JsonProperty("items")
    private List<T> items;

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    private MetaModel meta;

    public PageModel() {

    }

    public PageModel(int current, int limit) {
         this.items = new ArrayList<>();
         this.meta = new MetaModel(current, limit);
    }

    @JsonProperty("items")
    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    @JsonProperty("items")
    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    public MetaModel getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    @JsonProperty("meta")
    public void setMeta(MetaModel meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class MetaModel {
    @JsonProperty("total")
    private Integer total;

    public MetaModel() {

    }

    public MetaModel(int page, int limit) {
        this.page = new PageMetaModel(page, limit);
    }
    @JsonProperty("total")
    public Integer getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    @JsonProperty("total")
    public void setTotal(Integer total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SubjectModel {
    private String name;
    private StatusModel status;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public StatusModel getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(StatusModel status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

---

**DAO Classes -**

```
public class Page<T> {
    private List<T> items;
    private int count;

    public Page(List<T> items, int count) {
        if(items == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("items can not be null");

        this.items = items;
        this.count = count;
    }

    public List<T> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<T> items) {
        if(items == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("items can not be null");

        this.items = items;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

---

public class Subject {
    private String name;

```
private Integer passCount;
private Integer failCount;

public Subject(String name, Integer passCount, Integer failCount) {
    this.name = name;
    this.passCount = passCount;
    this.failCount = failCount;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getPassCount() {
    return passCount;
}

public void setPassCount(Integer passCount) {
    this.passCount = passCount;
}

public Integer getFailCount() {
    return failCount;
}

public void setFailCount(Integer failCount) {
    this.failCount = failCount;
    }
}
```

---

**Mapper Logic -**

```
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();

        modelMapper.getConfiguration()
                .setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STRICT);

        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Page<?>, PageModel<?>>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().getMeta().setTotal(source.getCount());
            }
        });

        modelMapper.addMappings(new PropertyMap<Subject, SubjectModel>() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                map().getStatus().setPassCount(source.getPassCount());
                map().getStatus().setFailCount(source.getFailCount());
            }
        });

        List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
        subjects.add(new Subject("Subject A", 10, 20));
        subjects.add(new Subject("Subject B", 8, 7));

        Page<Subject> page = new Page<>(subjects, 10);

        Type pageType = new TypeToken<PageModel<SubjectModel>>() {}.getType();
        PageModel<SubjectModel> pageModel = modelMapper.map(page, pageType);
```

It seems ModelMapper is not working and giving me `pageModel` with Subject class items instead of Subject Model class items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a fix for this issue: [modelmapper#380](https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/pull/380) and will cut a release this weekend.
Please take a look if this fix your issue. Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/modelmapper/modelmapper/pull/380 solves the problem. 
Thanks for the quick response. :)